# "HANDLE" is incompatible with parameter of type "HINSTANCE"

Tags: c, winapi

I had to update some strings since a few things had changed over the years but now it won't compile.  This was originally done in VS2010.  It was coded in Win32 API in C.  Now I am using 2012 and it threw these errors:

```
1   IntelliSense: argument of type "HANDLE" is incompatible with parameter of type "HINSTANCE"  
2   IntelliSense: argument of type "LRESULT (__stdcall *)(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)" is incompatible with parameter of type "DLGPROC"
```

And this is the edited program:

```
// NSIS stack structure 
typedef struct _stack_t 
{
    struct _stack_t *next;
    char text[256];
} stack_t;

stack_t **g_stacktop;


// Function prototypes
char *getvar(int varnum);
void setvar(int varnum, char *var);
int runDialogBox();
HBITMAP LoadPicture(UINT nID);
BOOL DrawPicture(HDC hDC, LPRECT lpRect);

// Global variables 
char szBuf[256]="";
char szError[4]="";
int nVarError;
int res = 0;
HINSTANCE g_hInstance;
HWND g_hwndParent;
int g_stringsize;
char *g_variables;


BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HANDLE hModulePar, 
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, 
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
LRESULT CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    static HBRUSH hBrushStatic;


void __declspec(dllexport) Show(HWND hwndParent, int string_size, char *variables, stack_t     **stacktop)
{
    g_hwndParent=hwndParent;
    g_stringsize=string_size;
    g_variables=variables;
    res = runDialogBox();
    if ( res == 0 )
        setvar(INST_1,"NO" );
    else
    setvar(INST_1,"YES" );
}

int runDialogBox()  
{
    int result = FALSE;
    result = DialogBoxParam(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG), NULL, DialogProc, (LPARAM)    (NULL));    

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Its an NSIS plugin, coded as a Win32 C dll.  I suppose I can chuck it all out and switch to MFC?  Simply put, it just shows a complex dialogue box (more complex than the native messagebox is capable of handling) and have it handled there instead.

Comment: It would save everybody a lot of time if you told us which lines had the error. Also, if you deleted all the lines of code that are not related to the problem.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Originally there was too little code.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's the Goldilocks problem. Too much, too little, just right. You have to find the smallest program that demonstrates the problem. For compiler errors, this is particularly easy because the code doesn't even have to run; it just has to trigger the compiler error.

Comment: Just wrong declarations, easy enough to fix.  The first argument of DllMain() is HINSTANCE, not HANDLE.  The return value of DialogProc() is INT_PTR, not LRESULT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code was written with `STRICT` off, apparently.  This is like disabling all compiler warnings; well-written code will work, but the tools can't help you find errors.  So I recommend leaving `STRICT` turned on in your project.

To eliminate the issue in the code you show, change the type of variable `hModule` from `HANDLE` to `HINSTANCE`.  Evidently `hModule` had type `HANDLE` because the `DllMain` parameter it came from was using `HANDLE`, but that's wrong too.  Use [the correct signature shown on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> ```
> BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
>                       _In_  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
>                       _In_  DWORD fdwReason,
>                       _In_  LPVOID lpvReserved
>                    );
> ```

It sounds like there's a problem with the signature of `DialogProc` also, but you haven't shown us its definition.  Perhaps you need to change its return type to `INT_PTR`, to match [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  Also, do yourself a favor and use a different function name.  As the doc says:

> *`DialogProc`* is a placeholder for the application-defined function name.

You shouldn't need a cast on the `LPARAM` argument either.

Comment: I never knew strict was off.  I just installed vstudio freshly on this desktop since my older computer is the one that had 2010 on it.

Comment: @Jon: Your signature for both `DialogProc` and `DllMain` don't match the documentation.  DialogProc should return `INT_PTR`.  DllMain's first parameter has type `HINSTANCE`.  Fixing those (and adjusting the type of the `hModule` variable) should cure the problem.

Comment: I changed to this: `INT_PTR CALLBACK dlgBox(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` but get an error: `argument of type "LPSTR" is incompatible with parameter of type "UINT"`.  The hModule parameter is also causing an issue.  Sorry for being so dumb today, it has been a LONG time since I did this project.

Comment: @JonWeinraub: I didn't see any lines calling `dlgBox` (formerly `DialogProc`) directly.  Can you please show the line with that error?

Comment: sorry... the comment field is weird when entering code... `result = dlgBox(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG), NULL, NULL); `

Comment: That wasn't supposed to actually call the dlgBox, just pass a function pointer. try `result = DialogBoxParam(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG), NULL, dlgBox, NULL);`

Comment: lol...oops, but still `IntelliSense: argument of type "HANDLE" is incompatible with parameter of type "HINSTANCE"`, on the first parameter.

Comment: @JonWeinraub: Did you change `hModule` and `hModulePar` to type `HINSTANCE`?

Comment: omg, i forgot the header file had it defined, i think its time for more coffee... but now it compiles and works, thank you so much!

Comment: I just noticed this fails in Windows XP.  I ran rundll32 foo.dll and its entry point and it gave me the error: `
The procedure entry point InitOnceExecuteOnce could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll. `  It works fine in Windows 7.

Comment: @JonWeinraub: Newer versions of the compiler generate code that doesn't load on XP (it uses functions, like that one, that don't exist).  There should be a "XP Targetting Pack" to bring back support, make sure you have installed it (comes with Service Pack 1) and [change your project settings to use it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/10/08/windows-xp-targeting-with-c-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx).